# Dielectric cylinder in uniform electric field: nonlong cylinder

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential, boundary-conditions

Problem of dielectric cylinder in uniform electric field is well known. For example, Jackson textbook or Griffiths textbook or online solution [here](http://www.physicspages.com/2012/10/20/dielectric-cylinder-in-uniform-electric-field/).

Solution always given for case of long cylinder. So that $z$ dependence is removed from solution of Laplace equation $\nabla^2 \phi = 0$ in cylindrical coordinates $(r, \theta, z)$. Solution in form $\phi = \phi (r, \theta)$ is given [here](http://www.physicspages.com/2012/10/20/dielectric-cylinder-in-uniform-electric-field/).

Now consider the case of nonlong cylinder. What are the additional boundary conditions on potential $\phi = \phi (r, \theta, z)$, compared to those of [long cylinder case](http://www.physicspages.com/2012/10/20/dielectric-cylinder-in-uniform-electric-field/)? Or, how to treat end effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved only numerically for example with integral equation.  van Bladel in his Electromagnetic Fields derives the so-called *Phillips Integral Equation* (Equation 3.152, in the 2nd edition) for points $\mathbf{r}\in S$ on the *surface* of the object$$\phi ^i (\mathbf{r})= \frac{\epsilon_r+1}{2} +\frac{\epsilon_r-1}{2} + \int_S \phi({\mathbf{r}}')\frac{\partial }  {\partial {n}'} \left ( \frac{1}{\left | \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}' \right |} \right ) {dS}'$$
Here $\phi ^i (\mathbf{r})$ is the external potential in which the homogeneous object of surface $S$ is immersed. Later van Bladel shows how to use this for a cube. Once you know the potential *on* the surface more conventional numerical methods are applicable. One can of course discretize Poisson's equation directly for the whole space, too.